# Avoid extra eol in echo

Tags: windows, command-line, echo

Echo produces an EOL and there is no way (at least it is very difficult to find) to echo EOL alone. 
The first problem is that

```
echo 0 > myfile & echo " 11" >> myfile
```

produces a file

```
0
 11
```

rather than

```
0 11
```

How can I avoid the extra EOL?

Comment: Stackoverflow duplicates: [Dos Batches: write to files without a line ending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480727/dos-batches-write-to-files-without-a-line-ending), [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files)

Comment: First on google:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line

Val: visit man7.org

Comment: @user3490702 First read the question and explain how Linux manual can be used in Windows cmd line.

Answer (score 3):

The question was tagged as Windows, my bad.... There is an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line

---

The echo man page specifies the `-n` option for not printing a newline:

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

In practice:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ echo -n "0" > myfile; echo " 11" >> myfile 
mtak@frisbee:~$ cat myfile 
0 11
```

Comment: Note the "Windows" tag on the OP. :)

Comment: Indeed, how can I use Unix maual in Windows command line?